# Why my notifications is not working on Swiftui

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, notifications

I am uploaded my project in GitHub, I need help for my notifications, they not working, I don't understand why. So I have time interval prayers and I need local notifications every start prayer time.

https://github.com/kamilproo/PrayerTime4/tree/main/PrayerKitBetaTest

my project)

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is here in `NotificationViewModel`

```
 let interval = -times.isha.timeIntervalSinceNow
 guard interval > 0 else {
        return
    }
```

It always return, because your interval is negative. And notification center doesn't add notification.

Actually I don't know your business case, but it could be something like this:

```
func scheduleNotification(times: PrayerTimes) { func scheduleNotification(times: PrayerTimes) {

...

let triggerDate = getTriggerDate(date: times.isha, timeIntervalMinutes: 1)
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(
            dateMatching: triggerDate,
            repeats: false
    )

...

}
```

Here is the helper func where you can pass your date and your interval

```
private func getTriggerDate(date: Date, timeIntervalMinutes: Int) -> DateComponents {
    // let triggerDate =  date.addingTimeInterval(Double(-timeIntervalMinutes * 60)) // notification will show 1 minute before date
    // return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.timeZone, .year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: triggerDate)

    let triggerDate =  Date().addingTimeInterval(10) // notification will show in 10 sec
    return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.timeZone, .year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: triggerDate)
}
```

Also you need this to be able to receive your notification, when your app is in foreground

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler([.banner, .badge, .sound])
}
```

Comment: I have a prayer schedule that is calculated using locations and dates. With what you sent, I'm trying to do it too, the notification is created but why is not shown. There are no mistakes

Comment: What do I have if I trigger schedule notification passing times.isha trigger: <UNCalendarNotificationTrigger: 0x6000035fedc0; dateComponents: <NSDateComponents: 0x600003789460> {
    TimeZone: Europe/Moscow (GMT+3) offset 10800
    Calendar Year: 2021
    Month: 2
    Leap Month: 0
    Day: 28
    Hour: 22
    Minute: 25, repeats: NO>> So notification will show at 22:25 GMT+3

Comment: If you allow to push into your repo, I'll push some code in different branch with my example, you can test it.

Comment: Here is the notification showed in 10 seconds after turning on the toggle. https://ibb.co/wJJ1ZXW

Comment: I think i am allow branch, try to do some code. I also wrote something, but another problem is that when I start it sometimes nothing works for me, I added saving the parameters, there probably needs to be done somewhere code like onAppear {getStart() functionalists }

Comment: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/kamilproo/PrayerTime4.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: I kind of gave access everywhere in the project settings, rechecked, maybe some kind of error. If it doesn't work, maybe you can write here what you want to do or write to me by mail, I'm from Russia, kamilproo@yandex.ru

Comment: I've sent en email with example.